# Consulta SQL en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo dos tablas que tienen los siguientes campos:

- **tabla1:** id, id_profesional, id_usuario, nombre, correo, sexo, fecha_nacimiento.
- **tabla2:** id, id_profesional, id_paciente, talla, pesoActual, fecha_actual.

¿Cómo hago una consulta para conseguir el nombre de la primera tabla y la fecha de la segunda donde el `id_profesional` tenga valor determinado?

```
$sql = "SELECT paciente.nombre, diagnostico.fecha FROM paciente 
INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id_profesional = diagnostico.id_paciente 
WHERE id_profesional=$_SESSION[id]";
```

Esto es lo que hice pero no devuelve nada.

> PD: acabo de modificarla debido a que no me di cuenta que la transcribí mal

Comment: 1º: ¿Las tablas se relacionan por estas dos columnas: `INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id = diagnostico.id_paciente `?; 2º: en el `WHERE` debes poner el *alias* de la tabla, dado que `id_profesional` existe en ambas, por ejemplo: `WHERE paciente.id_profesional=$_SESSION[id]`; 3º: El criterio podría estar mal, a no ser que tengas tu consulta en una cadena rodeada de comillas dobles (pon siempre el código en su contexto, aquí no se ve el contexto); 4º: Si todo lo dicho es OK, entonces imprime tu consulta y pruébala en la BD directamente, puede que no haya datos con ese `id_profesional`

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por responder, por estar esperimentando en busca de una solucion no me di cuenta como quedo, la consulta original seria esta, si esa es la relacion y como realizo un alias?

Comment: Se refiere a que tienes que poner `WHERE paciente.id_profesional` en vez de `WHERE id_profesional` en SQL por defecto no hace falta referenciar el nombre de la tabla a menos que el campo exista en ambas tablas.

Comment: Estas hablando de ejecutar la consulta con phpmyadmin pero lo que muestras es un código php... estás seguro que la pregunta está bien formulada? estás lanzando la consulta en phpmyadmin o en php? `$_SESSION[id]` tiene algún dato? y si lo tiene, las tablas tienen datos para ese usuario?

Comment: En mi comentario hice referencia a 4 aspectos básicos de depuración en un código. No entendí lo que me quisiste decir en tu comentario. Con respecto a las 4 cosas que te señalé antes, ¿las has entendido? ¿si no has entendido alguna, cuál no has entendido? ¿si las has entendido, has depurado esos 4 aspectos? ¿cuál es el resultado de esa depuración?

Comment: Esta relación me parece extraña: `INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id_profesional = diagnostico.id_paciente` ¿el identificador del paciente debe ser el mismo que el del profesional que le atiende? Eso parece poco probable, y es posible que por ese motivo no te devuelva ningún resultado tu consulta SQL. Más bien parece que debes hacer `INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id_profesional = diagnostico.id_profesional`.

Comment: ¿Imagino que `id_usuario` es el identificador del paciente e `id_paciente` es lo mismo?  Si no es lo mismo, ¿cómo podría obtener el `id_paciente` del usuario del que buscas el diagnóstico?

Comment: lo siento a todos, otra vez escribi mal , gracias por resaltarme el error. las tablas se relacionarían con id_profesional, @A.Cedano lo depure y el resultado fue vacio

Comment: Si te da vacío y confirmas que las relaciones están bien expresadas en la consulta entonces es posible que no haya coincidencias. Pasamos a un punto 5º: Separa en dos tu consulta y pruébalas por separado: `SELECT FROM primera tabla WHERE ...` y `SELECT FROM segundaTabla WHERE ...`

Comment: @LeandroVece, ¿podrías comprobar mis comentarios? Estás intentando buscar en la tabla `diagnostico` los registros que el identificador de paciente (campo `id_paciente`) sea igual que el identificador del profesional (campo `id_profesional`) que hay en la tabla `paciente`. ¿Es eso correcto? Imagino que no. Si nos pudieras poner dos o tres registros de cada tabla que deberían estar relacionados (censura o cambia los datos personales, pero no toques los identificadores) nos ayudaría mucho a solucionar tu problema. Por lo pronto voto cierre por no haber suficiente información para la resolución.

Comment: @gracias por responder, siento no conectarme tuve un accidente. la idea era conseguir traer nombre de las personas diagnosticada por cierto profesional. el campo id.paciente es incorrecto, aquellas tablas que tuvieran el mismo id_profesional, pero si, existiera un paciente que no tuviera diagnostico, que no lo tragera. espero poder explicarme

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo que no entiendo, y es: ¿Por que relaciones el `id_profesional` con el `id_paciente`?
No debería ser la misma columna que contenga el mismo dato?

```
INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id_profesional = diagnostico.id_profesional
```

Obviamente, desconozco además cuales serían dichas tablas y sus claves para relacionarlas.
Pero creo que tu consulta de:

> el nombre de la primera tabla y la fecha de la segunda donde el id_profesional tenga valor determinado

Debería ser más como

```
$sql = "SELECT paciente.nombre, diagnostico.fecha FROM paciente 
INNER JOIN diagnostico ON paciente.id_profesional = diagnostico.id_profesional 
WHERE id_profesional=$_SESSION[id]";
```

Lo que traería eso, son todos los diagnosticos con nombre del paciente y fecha del diagnostico de ese profesional.
Por lo que faltaría definir bien que es lo que realmente quieres traer.

Comment: gracias por mostrarme el error, lo que me gustaría traer serian solo aquellos pacientes que tienen diagnósticos, el nombre se encuentra en la primera tabla y la fecha del diagnostico en la segunda.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Esta respuesta debería ser un comentario para recabar información y sugerir pruebas, tal y como hemos hecho el resto y, como comprobarás, justo el tema del `INNER JOIN` lo comenté yo allí. Obviamente no conocemos la relación entre los pacientes y sus pruebas diagnósticas. Intentamos recabar esa información pero aún no nos ha respondido.

Comment: @LeandroVece entiendo, relacionados por `id_profesional`. Entonces, el `$_SESSION['id']` que estás trayendo, es la id de un profesional ? o es otra id diferente. Por que si, como dices, no te trae nada, puede que la id no sea una id_profesional. Algo que podrías hacer para poder encontrar más rápido el error o la falla, es pasar tu base de datos, para poder hacer la consulta y verificar que ID es las que estas llamando. Si la de un profesional, u otra id diferente.

Comment: exactamente, es el id_profesional, tendría que haber puesto un comentario. verifique la consulta y corregí los ids, solo que ahora trae todos los pacientes, y la fechas son rellenadas, incluso si no tiene una consulta relacionada. es rellenada con la primera que trae la tabla.